# How do I save (backup) my snippets in TextMate?

Tags: textmate

I have a bunch of custom textmate snippets and have been backing them manually.

However, I continuously update (& subsequently debug) these snippets so am having a hard time keeping them backed up (manually). There are, for example, a lot of versions of these snippets and I just need to lock them into version control somehow.

I don't even know their location. If I knew that maybe I could add a git repository(?)

Comment: *NOTE*: I've tried the drag & drop to create installer thing but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using a Git repository (or a different version control system) would be a sane way to deal with this.

There are several locations bundles are stored in as mentioned in [the 'Locating Bundles' section of the documentation](http://blog.macromates.com/2011/locating-bundles/). If you customize a bundle the changes will be stored in the following path:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Avian/Bundles
```

What appear to be bundle files are just regular directories, you can just 'cd' into them from the shell and start a repo. The bundles in this location only have the deltas from the original bundle in them. So no need to worry about updating the original bundles etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Are snippets stored in my bundle? I see the file but haven't been able to determine exactly what is in it. Doesn't appear to be clear text

Comment: answer to my question above: the .tmbundle files are actually folder file types. changing the extension momentarily reveals this. Snippets are inside, in clear-text xml style format.